# Java: Mock external library for testing

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, apache-zookeeper, powermock

My tests are way too slow because I am using a configurations library in my code that takes at least 100ms any time I set or get something.

I am using Java and the configuration library that I use uses Apache ZooKeeper to store the data.
I used Mockito and Powermock several times but never tried to mock an external library and I wondering if it is even possible.

```java
import org.HybridConfiguration;

public class VisitManagerClass {

    private static final String COUNT_ENABLED = "countEnabled";
    private static final String COUNT = "count";

    public static void pageVisited() {
        boolean isCountEnabled = HybridConfiguration.getBooleanValue(COUNT_ENABLED);
        if (isCountEnabled) {
            long currentCount = HybridConfiguration.getLongValue(COUNT);
            HybridConfiguration.setValue(COUNT, Long.toString(currentCount + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect to be able to mock the library HybridConfiguration so that tests could run without any delay.

Comment: Whether a class is yours or comes from an external library doesn't change anythingto how you mock it using mockito or powermockito. Why don't you just try doing it, the same way you've been doing before?

Answer (score 2):

The way to go is create a service-facade that hides all api-calls to config-library/Apache-ZooKeeper behind an interface. your app only communicates with the interface and all methods calls to config-library/Apache-ZooKeeper are done in your service-implementation.

For testing you can easily mock out this service.

For more details see [the-onion-architecture](https://jeffreypalermo.com/2008/07/the-onion-architecture-part-1/)